# Broadcast Upload Extension is suppressing the volume output from other applications

Tags: ios, xcode, broadcast, replaykit

I have successfully implemented **Broadcast Upload Extension** and I am able to record **video** and **audio from microphone**. In my SampleHandler class from the extension, I am handling **RPSampleBufferTypeAudioMic** and **RPSampleBufferTypeVideo** samples and save them in **.mp4** file.

During the recording output volume from other applications (ex. youtube) is very low. Is there anything that can disable this so that sounds from other applications are played with normal volume? I want to hear the audio output from the iPhone during the recording.

Similar situation is with the Screen recording from the ControlCenter. All sounds from other applications during the recording are with very low volume, but in the end when video is saved and played, sounds from other applications are with normal volume.

I want the `sounds` from other `applications` to be played with normal volume during the recording.

**Thanks in advance**